# Adding two times to the same hook breaks the functionality

Tags: hooks

I want to add two things to the java-mode-hook, but when I add the second one none of them is installed in the hook:

```lisp
;;; Java
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set 'compile-command
         (format "javac %s" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))))
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'compile)))

(defun msg ()
  (insert "Hello JAVA"))
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-p")) #'msg))
```

This makes the compile command also unavailable in java mode, but when I comment the second add-hook out the compile-command is bound correctly to C-c C-c:

```lisp
;;; Java
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (set 'compile-command
         (format "javac %s" (file-name-nondirectory buffer-file-name)))))
(add-hook 'java-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-c") #'compile)))

;; (defun msg ()
;;   (insert "Hello JAVA"))
;; (add-hook 'java-mode-hook
;;    (lambda ()
;;      (local-set-key (kbd "C-c C-p")) #'msg))
```

Now is C-c C-c the correct compile command. What is happening?

Comment: Tip: Don't use lambdas as hook functions. That makes it hard to remove etc. Use named functions.

Comment: I assume you have these in your init file. What does the hook look like after you start emacs with that init file? Go to the `*scratch*` buffer and type `java-mode-hook C-j`: edit the question and add the result.